# how to skip default headers while export to csv in web2py?

Tags: csv, web2py

how to skip default headers while export to csv in web2py?
I have added extra titles by defining it separately.

```
s = StringIO()
        csv_writer = csv.writer(s)
        # write first row with specified column headings/names
        field_names = ['UsrId', 'Category', 'Location', 'Name']
        csv_writer.writerow(field_names)
        self.rows.export_to_csv_file(s, represent=True)
```

**csv_writer.writerow(field_names)** - This line prints defined heading 
BUT **.rows.export_to_csv_file** again prints default heading in second row.
How to get rid of those default headings?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `export_to_csv_file` method takes a `write_colnames` argument:

```
self.rows.export_to_csv_file(s, represent=True, write_colnames=False)
```

Comment: One more think I m trying here - How can we exclude a column which is there in grid and not required in csv?   Please Help!

Comment: Dear Anthony, I actually tried the same solution from ur post on google groups. But there because of the spelling mistake I was not getting expected result. There mentioned set 'write_columns=False' where as it is 'write_colnames=False'. Pl correct there to avoid confusion. Thanks!